# skipping over null values in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, null, innerhtml

I am having difficulty in skipping over null values when using .innerHTML i have something like this:

```
var inputLastIndexValue = document.getElementById("FileCount").innerHTML;
var inputArray = [];

for(var indexCounter = 0; indexCounter <= inputLastIndexValue; indexCounter++){
    var elementID = indexCounter + ".File";
        console.log("ElementID: " + elementID);

        if(document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML)
        {
            inputArray[indexCounter] =  document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML;;
            console.log(inputArray[indexCounter] + ":" + indexCounter);

        }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is getting the names of files that I upload to populate an array in which I can search from. I know for a fact that this script halts and throws a null error when trying to find something that does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't access `document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML` if `document.getElementById(elementID)` is null.

You need to check whether the element itself exists.

Comment: It's worth noting here that in javascript, later comparisons are ignored if prior ones are true. So you can run the comparison to see if the outer one is null && then check if the inner one is null within the same if statement, and no null error will fire if the outer one is null, as long as you check them in that order in the same statement.

Comment: @joshstrike: However, his `innerHTML` probably won't ever be empty.

Comment: You mean check it by altering the code in this fashion? `if( typeof document.getElementById(elementID) != 'undefined' && document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML)`

Comment: @Popnoodles: `getElementById` returns `null`, not `undefined`.  Just `if (getElementById(...))` is enough (since `null` is falsy).

Comment: Ok , so OP needs to change the condition to `if( document.getElementById(elementID)  && document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML)`

Comment: The OP probably does not need to check `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that posted, i really appreciate the help. Ill reach out again when i get off work.